# Trying to run simple graphics program in c using command prompt

Tags: c

This is the following program.

```
#include <graphics.h>
int main(void)
{
 drawRect(50,100,200,150);
 drawLine(50,100,150,25);
 drawLine(150,25,250,100);
 drawRect(130,190,40,60);
 drawRect(70,195,40,30);
 drawRect(190,195,40,30);
 drawRect(70,125,40,30);
 drawRect(190,125,40,30);
 return 0;
}
```

and following is the error

```
C:\Users\Balavardhan\Desktop\New folder\c language>gcc z.c -o z.exe
z.c: In function 'main':
z.c:4:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'drawRect'; did you mean 'drawpoly'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      drawRect(50,100,200,150);
      ^~~~~~~~
      drawpoly
z.c:5:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'drawLine'; did you mean 'drawpoly'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      drawLine(50,100,150,25);
      ^~~~~~~~
      drawpoly
C:\Users\BALAVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMnl0ZM.o:z.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `drawRect'
C:\Users\BALAVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMnl0ZM.o:z.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `drawLine'
C:\Users\BALAVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMnl0ZM.o:z.c:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `drawLine'
C:\Users\BALAVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMnl0ZM.o:z.c:(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `drawRect'
C:\Users\BALAVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMnl0ZM.o:z.c:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `drawRect'
C:\Users\BALAVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMnl0ZM.o:z.c:(.text+0xe2): undefined reference to `drawRect'
C:\Users\BALAVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMnl0ZM.o:z.c:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `drawRect'
C:\Users\BALAVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMnl0ZM.o:z.c:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `drawRect'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: drawRect and drawLine functions are not defined. This means you have to add the header file that define them. Use a tool to scan all .h files to find where the functions are defined. btw: which development tool chain do you use on which operating system?

Comment: Where do you think that `drawRect` and `drawLine` are declared? In which header? Where in your code (which you do not show as a [mre] but should ...) do you include that header?

Comment: "Undefined references" are reported if you fail to provide the definitions of the mentioned functions. They are not implemented by you or you don't link the necessary library that contains these functions. Show us a [example] and the command lines to compile and link. Oh, please [edit] your question to add new information. You might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: drawRect and drawLine are declared in graphic.h header file Yunnosch .

Comment: I assure you they're not declared in that header file.  Perhaps you're misspelling the function name?

Comment: Poking around I see a `graphics.h` that's a c++ header.  If that's what you're using, you'll need to make your program in that language.